# Two child Objects in inner query

Tags: apex, soql

I want to bring details of two objects in a single query.
suppose Acccount is parent and I want to bring details of Contact and Opportunity in a single query. Is it possible to fetch the data in inner query of both contact and opportunity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can as in below query.

```
List<Account> accountsWithChildren = [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM
Opportunities), (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account];
```

If you need to refer the children in apex, you can use sample like,

```
for(Account a : accountsWithChildren){
    for(Contact c : a.Contacts)
        System.debug('contact : ' + c.Name);
    for(Opportunity o : a.Opportunities)
        System.debug('opportunity : ' + o.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contacts), 
                 (SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunities) 
  FROM Account
```